# Why is my data-structure slow(custom data-structure)

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm trying to implement a data-structure that was a challenge from www.topcoder.com , but I'm not able to get the same speed/efficiency as they did.

This is what they're asking.

**QUESTION:**

Implement a BlockedList class that implements the List interface.  You may use any of the classes in JCF. The constructor for this class takes an integer block size b and the implementation should have these performance characteristics: 
get(i) and set(i,x) should run in O(1) time per operation
add(i,x) and remove(i) should run in O(b+ min{i, n-i}/b) amortized time per operation.

**Solution(Incorrect, which It should be a lot faster :()**

```
import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * This is a copy of the JCF class ArrayList. It implements the List
 * interface as a single array a. Elements are stored at positions
 * a[0],...,a[size()-1]. Doubling/halving is used to resize the array
 * a when necessary.
 * 
 *
 * @param <T> the type of objects stored in the List
 */
class BlockedList<T> extends AbstractList<T> {
    /**
     * List which will store elements
     */
    private List<T> list;
    /**
     * keeps track of the class of objects we store
     */
    Factory<T> f;

    /**
     * The number of elements stored
     */
    int n;

    /**
     * The block size
     */
    int b;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param t the type of objects that are stored in this list
     * @param b the block size
     */
    public BlockedList(Class<T> t, int b) {
        this.f = new Factory<T>(t);
        this.n = 0;
        this.b = b;
        this.list = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public int size() {
        return n;
    }

    public T get(int i) {
        if (i < 0 || i > n - 1) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        return list.get(i);
    }

    public T set(int i, T x) {
        if (i < 0 || i > n - 1) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        return list.set(i, x);
    }

    public void add(int i, T x) {
        if (i < 0 || i > n) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        if (i >= b ) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        list.add(i,x);
        n+=1;
    }

    public T remove(int i) {
        if (i < 0 || i > n - 1) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        T val = list.remove(i);
        n-=1;
        return val;
    }
}
```

**GOAL**

The goal is to complete the challenge as they requested, but I've tried it multiple times that I just gave up now. I would like to know what I've donee wrong. Also the speeds like I mentioned earlier for the get(i) and set(i,x) should run in O(1) time per operation
add(i,x) and remove(i) should run in O(b+ min{i, n-i}/b) amortized time per operation.

**Testing error:**

```
Executing: javac ListTest2.java
Running: java ListTest2 20
Running with n = 20
Correctness testing for topcoder.BlockedList...Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at topcoder.BlockedList.checkBounds(BlockedList.java:67)
    at topcoder.BlockedList.add(BlockedList.java:43)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
    at topcoder.sanityTests(ListTest2.java:30)
    at topcoder.main(ListTest2.java:115)

Program exited with non-zero status, test failed
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't actually do any blocking.  You're supposed to store *n* > *b* elements in blocks of *b* elements.  Your implementation just refuses to support *n* > *b*.

Actually, on reflection I didn't answer the question "why is it slow?".  But that seems secondary to "it doesn't satisfy the requirements".

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `java.util.Map<Intger, T[]> blocks = new HashMap<>();`.

And do better than:

```
if (i >= b ) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
```

Complete source (little tested):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class BlockedList<T> extends AbstractList<T> {

    static class Factory<T> {

        private final Class<T> clazz;

        public Factory(Class<T> clazz) {
            this.clazz = clazz;
        }

        public T[] createBlock(int b) {
            return (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, b);
        }
    }
    private int n;
    private final Map<Integer, T[]> blocks;
    private final int b;
    private final Factory<T> f;

    public BlockedList(Class<T> tclass, int b) {
        this.f = new Factory<>(tclass);
        this.n = 0;
        this.b = b;
        this.blocks = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return n;
    }

    public long capacity() {
        return blocks.size() * b;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        blocks.clear();
        n = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public T get(int i) {
        checkBounds(i);
        return blocks.get(i / b)[i % b];
    }

    @Override
    public T set(int i, T x) {
        checkBounds(i);
        final T[] block = blocks.get(i / b);
        final T retVal = block[i % b];
        block[i % b] = x;
        return retVal;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int i, T x) {
        checkBoundsAdd(i);
        if (blocks.containsKey(i / b)) {
            blocks.get(i / b)[i % b] = x;
        } else {
            T[] tmp = f.createBlock(b);
            tmp[i % b] = x;
            blocks.put(i / b, tmp);
        }
        n++;
    }

    @Override
    public T remove(int i) {
        checkBounds(i);
        T val = blocks.get(i / b)[i % b];
        if (val != null) {
            n--;
        }
        return val;
    }

    private void checkBounds(int i) {
        if (i < 0 || i > n - 1) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
    }

    private void checkBoundsAdd(int i) {
        if (i < 0 || i > n) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test();
    }

    private static void test() {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        BlockedList<Integer> test = new BlockedList<>(Integer.class, 8);
        for (int i = 0; i < Short.MAX_VALUE - 7; i++) {//Integer.MAX_VALUE takes toooo long
            test.add(i, rnd.nextInt());
        }
        System.out.println(test.size()); //Short.MAX_VALUE - 7
        for (int i = 0; i < Short.MAX_VALUE - 107; i++) {
            test.remove(rnd.nextInt(test.size()));
        }
        System.out.println(test.size()); //expect: 100
        test.forEach((_item) -> {
            test.set(rnd.nextInt(test.size()), rnd.nextInt(1024));
        });
        System.out.println(test.size()); //expect: 100
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test.toArray()));
        test.set(0, 0);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test.toArray()));
        Collections.sort(test);
        //test.toArray() uses test.get(int)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test.toArray()));
    }
}
```

... now we'd have to decide for "the nicest" map implementation (I waver between `TreeMap` and `HashMap`).

So far we have up to `n / b` entries/blocks, with `b` reserved size per block, which, with HashMap, almost meet the complexity requirements:

- get: `O(1)` (from HashMap.get)`+ O(1)` (from array get).

  - with `java.util.TreeMap`, it'd be `O(log(2, n/b) + 1)`.
- set: `O(1 + 1)`.

  - this is also more expensive with `TreeMap`: `O(log(2, n / b) + 1)`.
- add: `O(n / b + b)`.

  - TreeMap(i suppose): `O(log(2, n / b) + b)` (which 'd be better!)
- remove: `O(n / b + b)`

  - TreeMap: `O(log(2, n / b) + b`. (better)

---

And actually `O(min(i, n - i)) == O(n / 2) == O(n)` !?

So `HashMap` for faster get & set operations, `TreeMap` for faster add & remove, alternatives? (LinkedHashmap? ...)

Comment: I tested it again, I'm still getting the same error as above.

Comment: i could not reproduce your indexoob, but after writing some simple tests, i found "arraylist resizing issues" on `remove`, though it is nice, that `ArrayList` shrinks the memory used, but not appropriate for our case, solution: use (constant size) `new T[b]` (-> problem: "generic array instantiation", solution: factory!;) @TopCoderChallenges

Comment: due to size stability + `checkBounds`, we can also omit the null checks like `if(blocks.get(i / b) == null)...`